# PHPUnit in Eclipse shows library not found popup message

Tags: php, eclipse, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm running Eclipse Oxygen.1, PHP 7.1, and PHPUnit 6.4.3. In Eclipse:

*Project > Properties > PHP > Source Paths > Include Path > Libraries*,

I clicked *Add External PHARs...* and pointed the file chooser to the home of where I downloaded and renamed PHPUnit, `c:\php\latest\phpunit\phpunit.phar`.

I followed the install instructions from here: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

This is my code:

`CalculatorTest.php`

```
<?php
require 'Calculator.php';

class TestCalculator extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

private $calculator;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        $this->calculator = NULL;
    }

    public function testAdd() {
        $result = $this->calculator->add(1, 2);
        $this->assertEquals(4, $result);
    }

}
```

`Calculator.php`

```
<?php
class Calculator {

    public function add($x, $y) {
        return $x + $y;
    }

}
```

When I go to *Run > Run As > PHP Unit Test*, Eclipse throws this popup window:

```
Unable to find PHPUnit phar.  Check PHPUnit configuration.
```

I don't understand why this occurred.  In the project tree, I can expand `c:\php\latest\phpunit\phpunit.phar` and see all the packages. I'm really confused here.

[image: Screenshot of Preferences > PHP > Tools > PHPUnit]

Comment: What are your settings in _Window > Preferences: PHP > Tools > PHPUnit_?

Comment: @howlger, it says:  PHPUnit Phar: C:\php\latest\phpunit\phpunit.phar.  I added a screenshot to the original question for you.