# Unable to find PHPunit phar. check php unit congifurations:eclipse oxygen

Tags: php, html, eclipse

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCfv5.png)[[image: i'm running the code and getting the followed error]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koLgI.png)
When I go to Run > Run As > PHP Unit Test, Eclipse throws this popup window:
`Unable to find PHPUnit phar.  Check PHPUnit configuration.`

The other projects in this eclipse running fine(giving output)except this upload project
I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820319/phpunit-in-eclipse-shows-library-not-found-popup-message) but i found no solution there.
I tried changing different setting in eclipse but of no use.
I'm attaching my property tree structure image.
[image] 
[image]
help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I tried different setting changes but no thing helps me.

I tried of running in different platforms(run as-->run on server/php cli application/php web application /php unit test).

This works for me

Finally my project working fine on :

Run as --> `PHP web Application`

Comment: Worked for me after I corrected the bad URL pathname that Eclipse generated.

Answer (score 1):

Perform following step.

Project -> Properties -> PHP -> Source Paths -> Include Path -> Libraries
 then add libraries what you required.
or
check [This Link](https://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php?title=Configure_Eclipse_for_PHPUnit). it works.

Comment: still the problem exists.

Comment: added image after process as u said..showing the same error.pls see the image shown above

Comment: I'm getting the error on a trivial program that does not use include files or libraries. Doesn't inspire confidence. Shouldn't software tools just work?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse preferences -> PHP -> PHPUnit, select corect .phar.

phpunit.phar can be overriden in run/debug configurations.

For composer projects, PDT use phpunit from vendor dir if available.

Comment: Any clue as to what a "phar" is? Or a PHPUnit?

Comment: Since 4.0 PHPUnit is no longer released as pear package, but via pear. In short phar is JAR for PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php. PDT can consume PHPUnit from PHAR (you have to download and select correct package), or can use phpunit installed via composer.

Comment: Okay, "phar" is an archiving class for PHP files (never mind that .zip and .gz are already standard, we have to reinvent it for PHP). What is "phpunit"? I should have just looked it up instead of asking: it is a free system for unit-testing large PHP programs. It depends on PHAR being installed. Why doesn't Eclipse just tell us these things up front? Anyway, I tried Eclipse as a text editor and then moved on (ended up with UltraEdit).

Comment: phar (like jar) is already zip. You can run php *.phar, and will be correcty executed. It have declared "main" script and also another internal resources. Sorry it's basic knowledge about PHP, similar to basic knowledge about Java to know what JAR is. So if IDE tell you that you need phpunit phar, it exactly mean you have to download phpunit phar: https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html